# Register CRM 2011 Plug-in on Import

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

How can a plug-in be registered on an import?
There are messages 'Import' and 'Import All'. How are they used?

I want to create a single record after an import to a specific entity.
I tried to use 'Import', but I do not know what `context.InputParameters["Target"]` is. The plug-in did not fire when I imported a CSV.

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer right now so it's unchecked but spontaneously I'd say that you should be listening to *Update* message in the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the off-the-bat answer. I am registering the plug-in on Create; although I would really like the plug-in to fire only once for the whole import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Update* and *Create* messages. Now, I understand that you'd like to limit the execution to just a single (and last) instance. Technically, can't be done. Each *Update* and *Create* will invoke the plugin individually.

**But**, there's work-around. Not proud of it but yes, I did it. Once.

```csharp
public void Execute(...)
{
  Entity entity = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;
  bool isTheLast = entity["someField"] == "Viltersten is Godlike";
  if(!isTheLast)
    return;
}
```

This can be made shorter, doing it in one line. I'm just trying to be pedagogical. Also, I haven't checked the exact syntax but you get the point. Make the last thingy you import named something unique. Then, let the plugin fire all it want. Only one instance can pass.

This will be FUBAR if you can't control the order of imports.

In my case, I couldn't. My solution to that was to introduce a new entity, called *Controller*. After all the imports, I created a new instance of it. In there, I did performed all the operations needed to the **other** entities.

Braggable? Hardly. Workable? Yes.

Comment: Thank you. I created a record - with the same importsequencenumber - of a separate entity for the import. The plug-in checks if a record with the same sequence number of the other entity exists and creates a record if not. I found that even with the check in place multiple records where being created, that must be because of threading. I introduced another condition to check if more than one record was returned and deleted the extra if so; the delete had to be in a try{} because multiple instances ended up trying to delete the same record!

Comment: Cool. Horrible to debug (especially if you're at on-line) but cool. I haven't experienced **that** particular issue but you're doing more complex operation that what I did, probably. Nice to know those things so I know what to watch out for. Also, please feel free to edit my answer if you'd like to change the example code snippet. I'm feeling a bit too lazy, while you've got the stuff freshly in your head.

Answer (score 4):

Import is creating/updating entities so you should be able to fire a plugin based on the Create and Update messages

Comment: This approach works. The only downside is that the plug-in fires for every row in the import.